# PIXI.js sprite loses rotation after applying filter

Tags: javascript, webgl, pixi.js

I am first rotating a sprite which has a texture applied, then applying a filter with a fragment shader which causes distortion on the sprite. However, when I add the filter to the sprite, it rotates to normal horizontal position instead of the angled position it had before.

I have tried to apply a rotating function inside the shader to rotate the uv. This rotates the image but changes the image outside the parts that are rotated. Here are some screenshots.

Initial look of the sprite after adding and changing the angle:

[image]

How it looks after applying the filter:

[image]

As you can see the rotation is removed.

I tried to add a rotation matrix inside the shader, here is the result:

[image]

The rotation is correct, but only the texture is rotated and not the actual container.
Applying angle back to sprite does nothing.

The actual result should be first + second image, so that the filter applies on the rotated sprite.

Here is the code that adds the filter to the image:

```html
const filter = new PIXI.Filter(null, getTransitionFragmentShader(transition, 2), uniforms);
  filter.apply = function (filterManager, input, output, clear) {
      var matrix = new PIXI.Matrix();
      this.uniforms.mappedMatrix = filterManager.calculateNormalizedScreenSpaceMatrix(matrix);
      PIXI.Filter.prototype.apply.call(this, filterManager, input, output, clear);
  };

  sprite.filters = [filter];
```

```html
vec2 rotate(vec2 v, float a) {
                  float s = sin(a);
                  float c = cos(a);
                  mat2 m = mat2(c, -s, s, c);
                  return m * v;
                }

                vec4 transition (vec2 p) {
                  float dt = parabola(progress,1.);
                  float border = 1.;
                  vec2 newUV = rotate(p, angle);
                  vec4 color1 = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);
                  if (fromNothing) {
                    color1 = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);
                  } else {
                    color1 = texture2D(uTexture1, newUV);
                  }
                  vec4 color2 = texture2D(uTexture2, newUV);
                  vec4 d = texture2D(displacement,vec2(newUV.x*scaleX,newUV.y*scaleY));
                  float realnoise = 0.5*(cnoise(vec4(newUV.x*scaleX  + 0.*time/3., newUV.y*scaleY,0.*time/3.,0.)) +1.);
                  float w = width*dt;
                  float maskvalue = smoothstep(1. - w,1.,p.x + mix(-w/2., 1. - w/2., progress));
                  float maskvalue0 = smoothstep(1.,1.,p.x + progress);
                  float mask = maskvalue + maskvalue*realnoise;
                  float final = smoothstep(border,border+0.01,mask);
                  return mix(color1, color2, final);
                }
```

This is the shader code with ommitted functions for brevity.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did, was instead use a vertex shader for rotation as follows:

```html
attribute vec2 aVertexPosition;

      uniform mat3 projectionMatrix;
      
      varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
      
      uniform vec4 inputSize;
      uniform vec4 outputFrame;
      uniform vec2 rotation;

      vec4 filterVertexPosition( void )
      {
          vec2 position = aVertexPosition * max(outputFrame.zw, vec2(0.)) + outputFrame.xy;
          vec2 rotatedPosition = vec2(
            position.x * rotation.y + position.y * rotation.x,
            position.y * rotation.y - position.x * rotation.x
          );
      
          return vec4((projectionMatrix * vec3(rotatedPosition, 1.0)).xy, 0.0, 1.0);
      }
      
      vec2 filterTextureCoord( void )
      {
          return aVertexPosition * (outputFrame.zw * inputSize.zw);
      }
      
      void main(void)
      {
          gl_Position = filterVertexPosition();
          vTextureCoord = filterTextureCoord();
      }
```

Rotation is passed as pair of sine, cosine of angle [sine(radians), cosine(radians)].